# How to query a document in mongodb comparing fields from an array?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, database, nosql

if i have this collection:

```
db.createCollection("misMensajes", {max: 100});
```

And  documents with this distribution:

```
    db.misMensajes.insert(
    {
    "FechaEnvío": new Date("2015-06-22"),
    "Texto": "bla",
    "Destinatarios":[
        {
            "Nombre": "Pepa",
            "Edad": 15,
            "Apodo": "P"
        },
        {
            "Nombre": "Juan",
            "Edad": 16,
            "Apodo": "J"
        }
    ]
    }
);
```

What i want to do is a query to get the documents that have for "Destinatarios" "Edad" greater than 15 and less than 18. 
I don't know how to query "inside" the array "Destinatarios". I am starting in mongo and I don't understand many things. What I have until now is:

```
db.misMensajes.find({
    $and:[
        {Edad:{$gt:15}},
        {Edad:{$lt:18}}
    ]
});
```

But this is not giving me what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To query inside an array, you need to use the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation) for the field name, `Destinatarios.Edad` in this case:

```
db.misMensajes.find({
    $and: [
        { 'Destinatarios.Edad': { $gt: 15 } },
        { 'Destinatarios.Edad': { $lt: 18 } }
    ]
})
```

Also note that you don't need `$and` in this case:

```
db.misMensajes.find({
    'Destinatarios.Edad': { $gt: 15, $lt: 18 }
})
```

For more complex queries, you might need to use [the `$elemMatch` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch).

Answer (score 0):

Please use **$elemMatch**. Here is the query.

db.misMensajes.find(    { Destinatarios: { $elemMatch: { $and:[ {Edad:{$gt:15}}, {Edad:{$lt:18}} ] } } } );

Answer (score 0):

Refer the [find-doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#query-fields-of-an-embedded-document) to have a better understanding on how to use find query based on fields of an array.

To do find based on greater than and less than (as per your requirement) value, use [$gt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/) and [$lt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/lt/) of mongodb.

So your can use as below :-

```
db.misMensajes.find({
$and: [
    { 'Destinatarios.Edad': { $gt: 15 } },
    { 'Destinatarios.Edad': { $lt: 18 } }
]
}).toArray(function(err, result)
   {
       console.log(results); //results will be an array of objects, containing all the records, which matches the query
    }
```

> NOTE:- The above query will return the parent record, which matches the condition.
>
> `Destinatarios` will have all the objects, not only the objects that matches the query.

If you want to get specific objects of `Destinatarios` array, you have to use [aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/).

Comment: Thak you! it really helps!

Comment: Glad it helped you.